# How to send E-Mail from Docker Container using php mail() function

Tags: php, docker, sendmail

I have a docker container built from this dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.2-apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod include

ENV PORT=80
```

I want to send an e-mail from php using it's mail() function.
What do I have to set up?
Does sendmail/PHPmailer do what I want? And if it does, how do I install and configure it?

I'm on a Windows 11 host in case this matters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure sendmail inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215021/configure-sendmail-inside-a-docker-container)

Comment: Also, using PHP's `mail()` directly will cause tons of trouble. Use a proper library to handle mails (like SwiftMailer, PHPMailer, Symfony's Mailer)

Comment: "Does sendmail/PHPmailer do what I want?" - even if these are two completely different things: yes, they might work